# Retry only failed observable RxJava 2

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm trying to run a long running task that might fail for some objects in a list I tried retry but it resubscribes to the entire list of observables. I can do nested subscriptions but it seems wrong. Is there any better solution than nesting subscriptions?

Here is my implementation:

```
public Observable<ReportItemModel> deferReports() {
        return  Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends ReportItemModel>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<? extends ReportItemModel> call() throws Exception {
                return Observable.fromIterable(getReports())
                        .map(new Function<Report, ReportItemModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public ReportItemModel apply(Report report) throws Exception {
                                return report.getReport();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
}

reportFactory.deferReports()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .retry()
            .subscribe(new Observer<ReportItemModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ReportItemModel value) {
                    Log.d(TAG,value.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            });
```

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think you just have `retry()` in the wrong place. If an error occurs from `getReports()`, then the error will propagate to the call to `deferReports()`; this will retry `deferReports()`. Instead, place `retry()` here: `Observable.fromIterable(getReports()).retry().map(...);` to retry a response from `getReports()`.

Comment: `retryWhen()` or `doOnError()`?

Comment: @Bryan  the error comes for getReport.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin

Comment: You said about 'long running' and a 'list' but I do not see any signs of these in your code. Tell more about `getReports()`, whether it is blocking, what it returns, etc.